# What is the correct way to include a Map<Entity, Entity> field

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, jpa, cascade

I've got an entity class `MyEntity` that can be associated with other `MyEntitys`.  I want to define the relationship between the MyEntitys.  So I've ended up with a class like

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String phone;

    @NonNull
    @OneToOne
    private MyEntityType myEntityType;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Map<String, Address> addresses = new HashMap<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable()
    private Map<Relationship, MyEntity> relationships = new HashMap<>();

    public MyEntity addAddress(String key, Address address) {
        addresses.put(key, address);
        return this;
    }

    public MyEntity addRelationship(Relationship relationship, MyEntity myEntity) {
        relationships.put(relationship, myEntity);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Where the relationship class looks like

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Relationship {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String antonym;
}
```

The field in question is the relationships field in `MyEntity`.

Things seem to work until I delete a MyEntity.  If the deleted MyEntity has no relationships everything is ok.  If the deleted `MyEntity` has relationships then the `MyEntitys` it is related to are also deleted.

If I modify the `@ManyToMany` annotation to

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
```

Then the related `MyEntitys` are no longer deleted.  Does this look like the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly define the `Map<Entity, Entity>` mapping you need to combine `@ManyToMany` (or `@OneToMany`), `@JoinTable` and the `@MapJoinColumn` annotations:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(...)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "relationship_id")
private Map<Relationship, MyEntity> relationships = new HashMap<>();
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) for more examples.